# Rake task errors with: JSON::ParserError: 765: unexpected token at '' but works fine in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, parsing

I have a rake task which loops over pages of card game database and checks for the cards in each deck. Until recently this was working fine (it's checked 34000 pages of 25 decks each no problem) but recently this has stopped working when I run the rake task and I get the error:

JSON::ParserError: 765: unexpected token at ''

In order to debug this I have tried running each line of the get request and json parse manually in the rails console and it works fine every time. Weirder still I have installed pry and it works every time I go through the json parse manually with pry (takes ages though).

Here is the rake task:

```
desc "Create Cards"
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
task :create_cards => :environment do
  # Get the total number of pages of decks
  uri = URI("https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/")
  response = Net::HTTP.get(URI(uri))
  json = JSON.parse(response)
  deck_count = json["count"]

  # Set variables
  page_number = 1
  page_size = 25 # 25 is the max page size
  page_limit = deck_count / 25
  card_list = Card.where(is_maverick: false)

  # Updates Card List (non-mavericks) - there are 740 cards so we stop when we have that many
  # example uri: https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/?page=1&page_size=30&search=&links=cards
  puts "Updating Card List..."
  until page_number > page_limit || Card.where(is_maverick: false).length == 740
    uri = URI("https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/?page=#{page_number}&page_size=#{page_size}&search=&links=cards")
    response = Net::HTTP.get(URI(uri))


    json = JSON.parse(response) # task errors here!


    cards = json["_linked"]["cards"]
    cards.each do |card|
      unless Card.exists?(:card_id => card["id"])
        Card.create({
        card_id: card["id"],
        amber: card["amber"],
        card_number: card["card_number"],
        card_text: card["card_text"],
        card_title: card["card_title"],
        card_type: card["card_type"],
        expansion: card["expansion"],
        flavor_text: card["flavor_text"],
        front_image: card["front_image"],
        house: card["house"],
        is_maverick: card["is_maverick"],
        power: card["power"],
        rarity: card["rarity"],
        traits: card["traits"],
        })
      end
    end

    puts "#{page_number}/#{page_limit} - Cards: #{Card.where(is_maverick: false).length}"
    page_number = (page_number + 1)
  end
end
```

The first json parse where it gets the total number of pages of decks works okay. It's the json parse in the until block that is failing (I've marked the line with a comment to that effect).

As I say, if I try this in the console it works fine and I can parse the json without error, literally copying and pasting the lines from the file into the rails console.

Comment: It's probably hitting some server error (400? 404? 429? 500?...) and returning a non-JSON error response. You could start by `rescue`ing the exception and looking at the full response to help diagnose it. Maybe your best bet is to just retry the request if it fails (a few times, before giving up and then failing more gracefully). But it's hard to say until we know what the actual error was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looping over an api, it's possible there are rate limits. Public APIs normally have per second rate limits.  You could try adding a sleep to slow down your requests, not sure how many your making per second.  I tested with a simple loop and looks like response returns an empty string if you hit the api too fast.

```
url='https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/?page=1&page_size=30&search=&links=cards'
uri = URI(url)
i = 1
1000.times do
  puts i.to_s
  i += 1
  response =  Net::HTTP.get(URI(uri))
  begin
    j = JSON.parse(response)
  rescue
    puts response
    #= ""
  end
end
```

I played with this until the loop stopped returning empty string after the 3rd request and got it to work with `sleep 5` inside each loop, so you can probably add as the first line inside your loop. But you should probably add error handling to your rake task in case you encounter any other API errors.

So for now you can probably just do this

```
until page_number > page_limit || Card.where(is_maverick: false).length == 740
  sleep 5
  # rest of your loop code, maybe add a rescue like I've shown
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I guess the rate limiting is something they added more recently on their end, and I hadn't considered using a begin rescue.